# App crashes after using `present` method

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to present a `UIViewController` like this:

```
let autocompleteVC = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
autocompleteVC.delegate = self
self.present(autocompleteVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The VC is shown for a second and then the app crashes, Xcode breakpoints on a non-relevant line (`self.buttonsScrollView!.frame.origin.y = (self.window?.frame.size.height)! - self.bounds.size.height`) in another class and if delete this line I get an `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` error.

*The question isn't what does `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` means - the question is why does it crashes when I'm using the `present` method.

Any idea why does this happen?

Thank you!

Comment: @dfd It's a `Google Places SDK` class. But I've also checked it with a regular `UIViewController()` and it was the same

Comment: @FS.O6  what about buttonsScrollView ? why you  force unripe ?

Comment: @NazmulHasan It's not relevant. It happens when I put `?` as well and even when I delete that line

Comment: @rmaddy this isn't a duplicate of `what does fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value means` - the question is why does it crashes when I'm using the present method.

Comment: It's crashing because you are force unwrapping an optional somewhere. That is your issue. The duplicate clearly explains what that error means and various ways to fix it.

Comment: @rmaddy it's not happens because I'm unwrapping an optional value. It's happening with EVERY ViewController.

Comment: Then you need to fix the forced unwrapping issue in all of your view controllers.